# How to Live Stream My Audio Inputs using flask web api

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to live stream my audio card audio inputs to the web, but my code just don't work

I tried to send the audio chunk from pyaudio to be returned through the flask api.

```
from flask import Flask, Response
import pyaudio


app = Flask(__name__)
CHUNK = 1024 * 4
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "voice.wav"
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
@app.route("/wav")
def streamwav():
    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                    channels=CHANNELS,
                    rate=RATE,
                    input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

    def generate():
        while True:
            frames = []
            data = stream.read(CHUNK, exception_on_overflow=False)
            yield data

    return Response(generate(), mimetype="audio/wav")

app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=1235, use_reloader=True, use_debugger=True, use_evalex=True)
```

The Above Code doesn't work the way i want, please show me some other way to live stream Audio Card Audio inputs to the web